# How can I get the request object in play2 framwork(scala)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

```
def index = Action{ request =>
    Ok(request.uri)
}
```

Is there any other way to get the request object?

Answer (score 1):

No. In the Scala version that's the only way.

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: There really isn't anything to explain. The OP is asking if there is another way to access the `request` within a controller, and the answer is no.

Answer (score -1):

```
val wsRequest = ws.url("yourURL");
```

this will return WSRequest in play2, later you can add query, headers and auth.

```
wsRequest.withQueryString()
wsRequest.withHeaders()
```

and finally we can say get or post,

```
wsRequest.get()
```